Anthropogenic relocation of Earth's mass
How much of Earth's mass would need to be relocated to cause catastrophic changes to its rotation or orbit, and how far would this mass need to be moved?

Incidentally this has already been suspected of occuring due to the shift of ground water to the surface, of course this doesn't directly answer your question but it does show that humans can have a noticable effect on earths rotation.

You're looking for this: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/

When a large artificial reservoir in Canada began to fill with water some years ago, the redistribution of that mass was sufficient to alter the earth's rotation by an extremely tiny, but measurable amount. I'll see if I can cite a reference.
